# What is the current kernel version of elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation, updates, kernel

I have AMD Ryzen 2200g APU and people said that it was unstable before 4.15 update and 4.17 update kinda has all issues fixed.

So what is current kernel version installed on elementary os?

Answer (score 2):

Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki currently uses:

4.15.0-33-generic

Answer (score 1):

you can find out what kernel you are using with the following command

```
sudo uname -a
```

Comment: No need for `sudo`, and it's not a good idea to use it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh installation today, Juno appears to run **Mainline Kernel 4.15.0-36.39**. If you can at least boot into eOS Juno then you can actually run newer mainline kernels using **UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility)**. This utility has been a life saver for me because I have gotten plenty of brand new hardware that really only had good support in the newest kernel releases. If you would like to try it out then you can install UKUU on eOS Juno by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ukuu
```